# .htaccess Remove file extension, force trailing slash and allow folder with same name as file

Tags: php, .htaccess

As the title says, i'm trying to remove all php-file extensions from URLs, and add a trailing slash to the url.

http://website.com/link.php

should be

http://website.com/link/

Also, if there's a folder with the same name (/link), the file (link.php) should be prioritized and displayed.

My current code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Manually re-route portfolio/ requests to portfolio
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} marknadsnytt/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 

# Hide extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate redirect rule for removing `.php` and adding trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't solve the problem with the files vs folders. If there's a filename (without extension) with the same name as a file, i want to open the file, and not the folder. So, /link should go to /link.php, but without the php extension. If we go to /link/file, we should open the file in the folder etc.

Comment: What is happening with this code when you visit `/link` assuming `link.php` exists?

Comment: Add `Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes` at top of your .htaccess and retest

Comment: nope that type of comment won't help, always provide details of error

Comment: And with `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f` ? (instead of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`)